# Polygon to Raster produces misaligned raster even at same resolution using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector-grid

In first image is a fishnet polygon. Using 'Polygon to Raster' tool, at SAME CELL SIZE of fishnet. I get image 2 (only few pixel shown to highlight misalignment).

[image: fishnet polygon]

[image: raster]

Is it possible to convert to raster such that it aligns with fishnet.

Comment: Did you set the extent to be exactly same as the fishnet polygon in the Environment?

Comment: I did not. Setting extent fixed it. thank you. I will delete question I guess.

Comment: No, do not delete the question. Answer your own question with some details.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solution based on above comments.

As per suggestion, I tried to set extent same as fishnet polygon, however the error stayed the same.

However I have another raster already with same pixel location. Selecting 'Snap Raster' to this raster in environment solved the problem